# Can I ignore typescript error while compiling with Angular 2 AoT?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

My app has a lot of TypeScript errors but runs properly (I moved a javascript app to typescript and can't fix all the type issues now...). I've set up my editor (webstorm) to ignore those errors and the app compiles.

Runnning the app (JiT) works well but when I try to compile the app (I have followed [this tuto](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)) with AoT I get all the TypeScript errors and the compilation fails. I can't paste all the errors (there are too many) but here is a sample:

```
Error at C:/app-path/services/app.service.ts:18:23: Property 'saveScroll' does not exist on type 'CanComponentDeactivate'.
Error at C:/app-path/services/app.service.ts:45:20: Parameter 'object' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/app-path/services/app.service.ts:48:24: Parameter 'mObject' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error at C:/app-path/services/app.service.ts:75:30: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FormBuilder'.
```

Knowing that I can't currently fix all the errors (but want to keep typescript), what should I do to be able to compile?

Comment: A developer generally wants to compile their own code. Using the `exclude` property in `tsconfig.json` helps with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the quickest solution is to disable the `noImplicitAny` setting in `tsconfig.json`. This fixes 2 and 3.

For the other type errors, where the compiler complains about missing properties, you can fall back to casting them to `any`.

Comment: Thanks, It helped to remove some of the errors but I still have a tons! Can I bypass them?

Comment: No, compilation errors cannot be bypassed, except noImplicitAny type checking

Comment: @ncohen, actually there is `transpileOnly`, you have only to find out, where to write it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by editing your `tsconfig.json`. Few things to suppress type checks are `strict , noImplicitOverride, noImplicitReturns ,etc`

For more options, refer below link and find your required configurations

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig

Otherwise, you can get it directly from official angular website's TS configuration page

https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration